# How to secure ClientID in OAuth2?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We want to develop an Angular 2 App with an external OAuth2 server (IdentityServer4).

We also want to identify each client for uniqueness. But how to protect the ClientID in the Angular 2 / Javascript source?
Do we have to work here with CORS and check for the origin of the request? Do we have to build a server-side application for the authentication?

Our Mobile App should use the ClientID 12345
Our Angular App should use ClientID 99999

But if anybody else would try to use ClientID 12345 it should be rejected.

What is the best practise here?
- Authenticate directly with Angular?
- Use for each angular App a Serverapp for Auth?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot authentication public clients - there is no secure way to do this.

Especially for browser-based clients, you can only use ownership of the public return URL to identity the client.

This has never been possible - and OAuth2 does not change that situation.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 works with a pair of important keys.

It's both ClientID and ClientSecret which are used to identify one app. The ClientID can be public it's the secret that needs to remain, well, secret :).

Since your code will be client side, this presents a problem. I am pretty sure there is an OAuth2 implementation which works client side only. I am not convinced about it's safety to be honest since everything you do client side is visible whatever you do.

What I did in situations like this was to have a little backend which was an extra layer between the client side app and the OAuth2 server. It could be a very simple MVC or a very simple WebApi2 and it would only present endpoints to be used by the front end but its main responsibility would be to take the call from the front end, add the keys and create the OAuth2 calls for use by the actual Resource Server. This way your keys are never stored on the front end and you can employ whatever mechanism you want to keep them safe on the back end side.

Just make you always pass these things in the Authentication Header and you always work with the Authentication / Resource server over an **https** connection.

Comment: So the best practise to hide the client secret is to always ship Angular with a server side application like ASP.NET Core which operates the authentication? I can not only run Angular on a CDN and interact with an OAuth 2 Server and protect the data? This is... not overwhelming.

Comment: there is a node package you can look into using : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server. Either way you need a back-end, either node or something else. You can't get away from the fact that you need the id and secret to be able to get a token. If you can find a way to store those securely on the front end side then you solved the problem.